# Ionic App restarts on Android 6 after selecting image via Cordova Camera Plugin

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, camera, cordova-plugins

I'm using Ionic App camera plugin to select some image. After selecting an image application restarts.

On Android 4.4 everything works just fine.

I've read that I can use other plugin like foreground camera plugin and some forks but all of it seems outdated and doesn't work on Android 6.

How to run Cordova Camera Plugin to select / make image ?